# MySQL не работает внешний ключ

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key

Здравствуйте! Проблема такая: создал 2 таблицы - "Группа" и "Студент". Связал их по полю группы. При добавлении данных не проверяется целостность, т. е. можно добавить студента в группу, которой нет в таблице "Группа"
SQL код таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE `gruppa` (


`grup_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `spec` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curator` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`grup_num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `student`(
`id` int auto_increment not null,
`FIO` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
`num_gruppa` INT NOT NULL,
primary key(`id`),
foreign key (`num_gruppa`) references gruppa(`grup_num`)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Пример запроса:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('1','1','1')
```

Таблица с группами - пустая

Comment: Чисто на всякий случай: добавьте пример инсерта, который работает, а не должен бы.

Comment: INSERT INTO student VALUES ('1','1','1') Таблица с группами - пустая

Comment: Не в комментарии, в вопрос. Заведите привычку всю важную для вопроса информацию добавлять прямо в вопрос. Комментарии могут в любой момент сгореть.

Comment: А если после этого селектнуть эту строчку, какая возвращается?

Comment: @D-side возвращает так как вставил. в таблице данные есть

Comment: ``ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`num_gruppa`) REFERENCES `gruppa` (`grup_num`))`` Этим заканчивается прямой копипейст из вопроса в REPL `mysql`. Сервер версии 5.7.19. Тут явно что-то ещё.

Comment: @D-side значит что-то с сервером. мб это где-то включается/выключается в настройках? чего еще не может быть. я просто скопировал то что писал в workbench

Comment: `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64414/discussion-between-alexandr-alexandr-and-d-side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Оказалось**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39616619#39616619), что проверки внешних ключей были тупо выключены:

```
mysql> SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
+----------------------+
| @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

...и их надо попросту включить (в рамках сессии):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

...возможно даже глобально, если это ваш сервер БД и вы удивлены, что он так настроен:

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```